# Use compressed JavaScript file (not run time compression)

Tags: javascript, python, extjs, embedded

I have to deploy a heavily JS based project to a embedded device. Its disk size is no more than 16Mb. The problem is the size of my minified js file `all-classes.js` is about **3Mb**.  If I compress it using `gzip` I get a **560k** file which saves about **2.4M**. Now I want to store `all-classes.js` as `all-classes.js.gz` so I can save space and it can be uncompressed by browser very well. All I have to do is handle the headers.

Now the question is how do I include the `.gz` file so browser understands and decompresses? Well i am aware that a `.gz` file contains file structure information while browser accepts only raw gzipped data. In that I would like to store the raw gzipped data. It'd some sort of caching!

Comment: I think that browsers have to send in headers that they accept gzip. Then if they do, and the web server does too, the browser will fetch the requested file, render it (say, php), and then gzip the results on the fly and send it all back to the browser. So the browser will receive a .js, but it will know that the content is gzipped. Maybe you can alter your web server and tell him to add "gzipped" in the response headers, but send the .js unaltered?
I guess seeding the .js file elsewhere is not an option.

Comment: it is doable, but you have to tune the headers. checkout http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2006/07/13/compressed-javascript/

Comment: @Ted i can not have any browser that does not detect it. For example Safari. Beside the article is 6 years old? does it still support by chance?

Comment: @zladuric this `on the fly` thing is not possible for me. For this I need original source. But I dont want to keep original source. I dont have space.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should gzip the stuff on the fly, I said you can give the gzipped file to the server and tell it to return it like a regular one, but with "encoding: gzip" header, like Alexandre answered you in his reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, when the "all-classes.js" file is requested, is to return the content of "all-classes.js.gzip" with the additional "Content-Encoding: gzip" HTTP header.
But it's only possible if the request contained the "Accept-Encoding: gzip" HTTP header in the first place...

Comment: Yes thats my plan. In fact it no accept-encoding: gzip is not passed, I'll uncompress on the fly.